# Docker : phpize cannot find config.m4

Tags: php, docker

I'm using [Laradock](https://github.com/LaraDock/laradock) on Windows 7. I need to install bz2 extension, so I edited the php-fpm Dockerfile-70 as below.

Added below code -

```
ARG INSTALL_BZ2=true
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_BZ2} = true ]; then \
    # Install the bz2 extension
    pecl install bz2 && \
    docker-php-ext-enable bz2 \
;fi
```

Then when I run `docker-compose build php-fpm` I get few following error. I did google search and tried suggestions, nothing so far worked.

> running: phpize
>
> Cannot find config.m4.
>
> Make sure that you run
>   '/usr/local/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the
>   module
>
> ERROR: `phpize' failed

Please advice on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the bz2 lib and the php extension like this:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libbz2-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install bz2
```